# asp.net membership dynamic users rights assignment issue

Tags: asp.net-membership, authorization, user-management

I'm working on User Role Management ASP.NET 4.0 with C#, but I have a specific: I have a main user or we can say Super Admin.

1. Super Admin can create the admin user or reseller user
2. Reseller user can further create users under them

But here a reseller user can get the limited accessed given by the Super Admin. In same way
the sub users of the reseller user get the permission to access specified pages only.

How to achieve this using membership role management?

I saw this article but it did not answer my question completely http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/role-based-authorization-cs